# text in label incorrectly displayed

Tags: qt, qt-designer, text-alignment, qlabel

I'm unable to correctly display a text on a `QLabel`, here's how it looks:

[image]

How do I modify it to get this result:

[image: The result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code: after create widget you can try to relocate your text using `setAligment` fuction, in class `QLabel`. For example, locating text from top to down:

```
myLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop)
```

In Designer you can use field `Aligment`-`Vertical`.

Answer (score 1):

From 4.3 and above, any designable [Q_PROPERTY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#Q_PROPERTY) can be set using the `qproperty-<property name>` syntax.

For your case, you could use the following stylesheet on your label:

```
qproperty-alignment: AlignVTop;
qproperty-alignment: AlignHCenter;
qproperty-wordWrap: true;
/*an addition in case it's useful to set text using stylesheets*/
qproperty-text: 'Mercredi 19.01.2021';
```

Sources:

- [Qt Forum: QLabel text align wit StyleSheet](https://forum.qt.io/topic/10695/qlabel-text-align-wit-stylesheet/)
- [Qt Docs: Setting QObject Properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties)